# adding and removing multiple div dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im a bit stuck. this is what it suppose to do. When you mouse over a menu item it slides out the next menu and adds a new vertical div which must be 5px wide in between the current div and the next but i can't add and remove the div. i have a condition that checks that the div is not the last on I've commented it in my code if you can help it would be appreciated. here is a sample [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gygk7/)

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.menu-item').mouseenter(function () {
            var curr = $(this).closest('.container');
            var next = curr.next('.container');

            next.animate({ 'left': curr.position().left + curr.width() + 5 });

            if(curr.index() < ($('.container').length - 1)){
                //here i need to add and remove a </div class="spacer"></div> to the right side
                of the current(var curr) div
            }

            var $index = curr.index() + 1;
            $('.container:nth-child(' + $index + ')').nextAll().each(function () {

                $(this).animate({ 'left': curr.position().left + curr.width() + 5 });

            });

        });
    });

.spacer
    {
        background-color:Red; width:5px; height:200px; position:absolute; z-index:1000;
    }

<table border="2" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div id="menu" style="background-color:Black; width:2000px; height:300px;top:5px; left:50px  ">
                <div class="container" id="1" style="left:0; width:200px; height:220px; z-index:999; position:absolute; background-color:Aqua">
                    <div class="menu-item">Menu Item 1</div>
                    <div class="menu-item">Menu Item 2</div>
                    <div class="menu-item">Menu Item 3</div>
                </div>
                <div class="container" id="2" style="left:0; width:200px; height:300px; z-index:998; position:absolute; background-color:Blue">
                    <div class="menu-item">Menu Item 4</div>
                    <div class="menu-item">Menu Item 5</div>
                    <div class="menu-item">Menu Item 6</div>
                </div>
                <div class="container" id="3" style="left:0; width:200px; height:400px; z-index:997; position:absolute; background-color:Fuchsia">
                    <div class="menu-item">Menu Item 7</div>
                    <div class="menu-item">Menu Item 8</div>
                    <div class="menu-item">Menu Item 9</div>
                </div>
                <div class="container" id="4" style="left:0; width:200px; height:500px; z-index:996; position:absolute; background-color:Green; float:left">
                    <div class="menu-item">Menu Item 10</div>
                    <div class="menu-item">Menu Item 11</div>
                    <div class="menu-item">Menu Item 12</div>
                </div>
                <div class="container" id="5" style="left:0; width:200px; height:600px; z-index:995; position:absolute; background-color:Lime; float:left">
                    <div class="menu-item">Menu Item 10</div>
                    <div class="menu-item">Menu Item 11</div>
                    <div class="menu-item">Menu Item 12</div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: :) what do you need exactly? Explain please, what DIV? 5px where? why? I cannot figure out from the example what's the porpouse of that div except the script seems strange till IS normal and natural in animations, that mostly, elements after a call returns to the previous state... The 2. DIV is catching my eyes

Comment: when you mouse over the menu item a another menu slides out and there i want to add a div 5px wide between the div.containers that slide right and left. also when i move backwards moving over the menu items i want to remove that div 5px wide between div.container.

Comment: if my code is wrong can you improve it please Im just learning jquery

Comment: you are concerned about the visible div transitions BETWEEN two opened div?

Comment: First of all You cannot set numbers as a first place(character) for an ID name. Rather change this to d1 d2 d3 d4 d5 d6 and so on

Comment: i added in my sample a css class .spacer which it's color is red and i am concerned about the div it's part of my small effect.

Comment: I only used that to keep track of my debuging thats why they are numbered

Comment: may you explane what should this magical 5px wide div do? so i can suggest you or start to play with something new. 'cause your script is slow and buggy.

Comment: it seperates the content beside the div.containers i know it sounds silly but i want that effect for this

Comment: ok what can I do too improve it it runs fine on my computer can you make it work better

Comment: Yes it sound silly. in a couple of hours (when i'll have more time) I'll try to play around a bit to help you in your plan. see ya soon (or good luck in the mid-time someone else helps you!)

Comment: please give it a go and help me cos i dont know much jquery and i don't know how to make it better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you need accordion. Why not just use one of the [million plugins available for jQuery?](http://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&source=hp&biw=1045&bih=524&q=jquery+accordion&aq=f&aqi=g10&aql=&oq=)

Comment: Doesn't necessarily warrant a -1 vote with the simple comment "I want something else" -- the lack of answers only confirms others are also confused what you want. Based on your code it's hard to tell. Please be more descriptive. Do you want something similar to horizontal sub menus, with a sliding from left-to-right effect?

Comment: Gary... don't worry. I'll give you a +1 :)

Comment: Thats the one gary i want horizontal sliding menu left to right that's what im doing